# Desktop Entry doesn't do anything

Tags: desktop-icons

I'm trying to create a desktop entry for an app. Here's what I've tried:

1. I created a .desktop file with the code:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=clash for windows
    Icon=/home/nadeko/Documents/Clash/Clash.png
    Exec=/home/nadeko/Documents/Clash/cfw
    Type=Application
```

I got both the location for Icon and Exec by right clicking and "copy" on the original file

This .desktop file is placed in "/home/nadeko/.local/share/applications"

2. Set both the application and .desktop file "allow executing"
3. Search in "search applications", but didn't see "clash for windows"
4. When right click on the .desktop file, there's no "Allow Launch" option.

What have I done wrong? Can anybody please help?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try adding a `Categories=Game` line to the bottom of your `.desktop` file.  There is a chance that it may not be needed, but in an experiment I ran my `.desktop` file did not show up when I had it in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory without it.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure the file path to your executable is correct.

The information you included is in principle sufficient to have a working `.desktop` launcher. The only "fatal" error, i.e., preventing the launcher to be displayed in the desktop's application menu, is the validity of your executable. There is no need, nor is it recommended, to mark the `.desktop` file as executable for it to appear in the desktop's application menu.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Step 3 says "Search in "search applications", but didn't see "clash for windows"", you might need a `Categories=` in your `.desktop` for it to show up.  *Not sure how Chrome Apps shows up since the `.desktop` files for it doesn't have a Categories= line.*
You can see https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html to determine what category you want to set your `.desktop` file in.

*Note:  `Categories=` is not needed if the file is actually in the `$HOME/Desktop` directory.*

As a test, I have a `Whatsapp.desktop` file that I will use for an example.  It looks like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=WhatsApp
Comment=WhatsApp
Exec=google-chrome --app="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Icon=/home/terrance/.local/share/icons/WhatsApp.svg.png
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Network
```

[image]

If I remove the `Categories=Network` line, we can see it no longer shows up in my menus:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cat .local/share/applications/Whatsapp.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=WhatsApp
Comment=WhatsApp
Exec=google-chrome --app="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Icon=/home/terrance/.local/share/icons/WhatsApp.svg.png
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

[image]

So, in your case add a line at the bottom that says `Categories=Game` and it should now show up.

Comment: Categories is not needed for a launcher - should also work without.

Comment: @vanadium It is not needed **if** the desktop file is on the actual Desktop.  The test here shows that it doesn't show up if the line doesn't exist if it is in the ~/.local/share/applications/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the .desktop file can't find the executable then it won't show up in the search.

I know you say you got the path by copying it but the screenshots show a different file-path to what's in your .desktop file.

Try the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=clash for windows
Icon=/home/nadeko/Documents/Clash\ for\ Windows/Clash.png
Exec=/home/nadeko/Documents/Clash\ for\ Windows/cfw
Type=Application
```

You can also try running `gio launch <path to .desktop file>` and it will tell you more info about what's wrong.